# "Incorrect" database value when attempting to update via form

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, database-connection

My issue is when I fill out the form which takes the "name" value, utilizes it, and will update all other fields associated with that value I get the "There is no instance of the submitted name in the database," when there definitely is. I've been working on this for hours and am completely stumped. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Quick Notes:
$host="localhost"
$pw=password (My personal password)
$db="akimble" (Database name)
tables name="pctable" (Tables name)
```

[phpMyAdmin Screenshot of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuT1x.png)
[Screenshot of Website Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymsMN.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Specifies Character Encoding Type (Unicode) -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Database One's Edit Entry Table</title>

    <!-- Beginning of CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 768px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 768px;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Arial, Helvetica;
    }
    table {
        width: 768px;
        border: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
    }
    td {
        border: 2px solid;
    }
    </style>
    <!-- End of CSS -->

    <!-- Beginning of Body Section -->
    <body>
        <!-- Start of Menu -->
        <table class="pheader" width="768px" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>Database One's Files Source Code</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="dbm"cellpadding="10" width="768px" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="add_form.php">Add to Database</a></td>
                <td><a href="search_form.php">Search Database</a></td>
                <td><a href="edit_form.php">Edit Database Responce</a></td>
                <td><a href="view.php">View Database Entries</a></td>
                <td><a href="pages_sources.php">View Database's Page's     Sources</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- End of Menu -->

        <!-- Start of Edit & Update Form -->
        <form action="edit_form.php" method="POST">
            <table cellpadding="10">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    Please enter the name used on the entry you wish to update     and edit:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    Please enter your central processing unit (CPU) model(s):
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" id="cpu" name="cpu">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    Please enter your motherboard model:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" id="motherboard" name="motherboard">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    Please enter your graphic processing unit (GPU) model(s):
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" id="gpu" name="gpu">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    Please enter your random access memory (RAM) model(s):
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" id="ram" name="ram">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    Please enter the storage device where your operating system (OS) is installed:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" id="storage" name="storage">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Update & Edit Entries">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
        <!-- End of Edit & Update Form -->

    <!--Beginning of PHP & MySQL Section -->
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $cpu = $_POST['cpu'];
        $motherboard = $_POST['motherboard'];
        $gpu = $_POST['gpu'];
        $ram = $_POST['ram'];
        $storage = $_POST['storage'];

        include ("connect.php");
//$host="localhost"
//$id="akimble"(My personal user account id)
//$pw=password (My personal password)
//$db="akimble" (Database name)
//table name="pctable" (Table's name)

        if ($name&&$cpu&&$motherboard&&$gpu&&$ram&&$storage){

        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", $id, $pw); //Start of Establishing Connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die ("Error connecting: " . mysql_error());
        }

        $update = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM pctable WHERE name= '$name'") or die ("There was an error with the query.");
        if (mysql_num_rows(!$update) != 0){
            mysql_query ("UPDATE pctable SET cpu='$cpu' WHERE name='$name'") or die ("There was an error updating.");
            mysql_query ("UPDATE pctable SET motherboard='$motherboard' WHERE name='$name'") or die ("There was an error updating.");
            mysql_query ("UPDATE pctable SET gpu='$gpu' WHERE name='$name'") or die ("There was an error updating.");
            mysql_query ("UPDATE pctable SET ram='$ram' WHERE name='$name'") or die ("There was an error updating.");
            mysql_query ("UPDATE pctable SET storage='$storage' WHERE name='$name'") or die ("There was an error updating.");
            echo "The update is complete";
        }
        else echo "There is no instance of the submitted name in the database";
        }
        else echo "Do not leave any fields empty";
    }
    ?>
    <!-- End of PHP & MySQL Section -->
    </body>
    <!-- End of Body Section -->

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using this site and I spend a while trying to format my code correctly for it!

Comment: Why don't you write one single update query?

Comment: Try check, before the loop,  if the content of $name is valid (eg: var_dump($name) and then be sure your value for $name match the values in db..

Comment: The statment  `if ($name&&$cpu&&$motherboard&&$gpu&&$ram&&$storage)` requires that all of the conditions (ie: condition1, condition2, condition_n) be must be met.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: As a friendly note, if you’re just getting started with PHP development and want to make applications, pick a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that suits your style and needs. These come with many examples that illustrate how to do exactly what you’re asking for here. Doing it all at the lowest possible level is extremely time consuming and error prone.